# Client authentication for rest api in tomcat

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, tomcat9, rest, handshaking

I have a Rest API and want to implement two way SSL in tomcat 9.I have imported client certificate in java cacert.  I have used following code.

```
<code>
    <Connector
       clientAuth="true" port="443" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="75"
       enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
       acceptCount="100" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/opt/server.jks" keyAlias="abc.com"
       keystoreType="JKS" keystorePass="password"
       truststoreFile="/opt/server.jks"
       truststoreType="JKS" truststorePass="password"
       SSLVerifyClient="require" SSLEngine="on" SSLVerifyDepth="2" sslProtocol="TLS"
    />
</code>
```

But this is not working.Right now apis are accessible from anywhere.

Comment: Any specific logging going on? Note that 8443 is not the default TLS port, that's 443. Have you imported any certificates for client authentication? Please edit details **into the question**. Currently I have voted to close because the given information is simply not sufficient (unless it is the port snafu).

Comment: I have used both the ports 8443 and 443 but didn't work.